# Java AppletRelaunch due to health

Tags: java, applet, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I have a web application that create/destroys several applets over its lifetime. Periodically, when creating a new applet, the JVM will inexplicably start a second instance. The applets share various memory structures, so a JVM relaunch causes failures throughout the application.

This is the only clue I have. In the console, this is what is written when an applet launch causes a new JVM to launch:

```
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.7.0_51
    requested: null
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: null
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
security: continue with running version
basic: AppletRelaunch due to health
network: Created version ID: 1.9
network: Created version ID: 1.8
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 1.6
network: Created version ID: 1.5
network: Created version ID: 1.4
network: Created version ID: 1.3
basic: WARNING - specified JRE version, null is invalid platform version
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@92c0c8
basic: Saving session state to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\session6130220480729710774
basic: Remote relaunch: LaunchJVMAppletMessage{appletID=16, conversationID=1, javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7, launchTime=132313312167, sendKill=false, [sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain, write_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2192_pipe22,read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2192_pipe21]}
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : 
into:
[]
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : -Xmx1g -Xms256m -Xss256k
into:
[-Xmx1g, -Xms256m, -Xss256k]
network: Created version ID: 2.0+
network: Created version ID: 1.6.0.10
basic: RemoteJVMLauncher.start(), pipe=Pipe{transport=WindowsNamedPipe: server: false; readPipe: jpi2_pid2192_pipe8, readBufferSz: 4096; writePipe: jpi2_pid2192_pipe9, writeBufferSz: 4096, initiatingSide=false} message: LaunchJVMAppletMessage{appletID=16, conversationID=1, javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7, launchTime=132313312167, sendKill=false, [sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain, write_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2192_pipe22,read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid2192_pipe21]}
basic: Thread[RemoteJVMLauncher-16,5,main] running...
basic: RemoteJVMLauncher.afterStart(): initializing streamers
handleLaunchJVM(): RemoteJVMLauncer.setCallBack for 16
```

Compare to this, which is written to the console during a normal applet launch:

```
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.7.0_51
    requested: null
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: null
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
security: continue with running version
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.51
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : 
into:
[]
```

Everything is the same right up to this line:

```
basic: AppletRelaunch due to health
```

Googling this gives me nothing. What does "health" mean? My intuition and the timing of the relaunch makes me think it's related to memory consumption, but java.exe always runs under 200mb, and I've tried increasing the memory limits using java_arguments (-Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k) to no avail.

Any ideas on what could be causing the relaunch? Is there some way to get even more information from HotSpot JVM to figure out what specific "health" check is failing?